# struct inner definitions differences in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, struct

I'm trying

```
typedef struct
{
    int x = 5;
    char str[20];
}  nodeStr;
```

It works in C++, but doesn't in C. For it to work in C I need to cut the definition of `x` (i.e., `= 5`) from the code. Is there in conceptual difference in C and C++ explaining this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In-class initialization is a new C++11 feature - if you use a (not much) older C++ compiler, it won't compile. So yes, it's a difference between C and C++.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, structs are almost the same as classes, so they can have constructors.

```
// note: removed the typedef to make it slightly clearer
struct nodeStr
{
    int x = 5;
    char str[20];
};
```

is the same as:

```
struct nodeStr
{
    int x;
    char str[20];

    nodeStr()
    {
        x = 5;
    }
};
```

C doesn't have constructors, so it can't do this.

That's the conceptual reason, anyway. The practical reason is either "because the language said so" or "because they never added that to C."

Comment: C99 did add [designated initializers](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html), something that's missing from C++. And to be pedantic, the equivalent code without non-static data member initializers would have the default constructor as `nodeStr() : x(5) {}`.

Comment: `nodeStr() {x=5;}` is keeping it easy to understand for someone who might not be very familiar with C++.

Comment: Is the first one a POD? Is the second?

Comment: @Luchian Neither is a POD. Adding of the NSDMI effectively defines a default constructor for `nodeStr`. immibis: `x = 5;` may be easier to understand for a novice, but that doesn't make it accurate, which is all I was saying.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore §9/4, C++ standard: `A POD-struct is an aggregate class that has no non-static data members of type non-POD-struct, non-POD-union (or array of such types) or reference, and has no user-defined copy assignment operator and no user-defined destructor. Similarly, a POD-union is an aggregate union that has no non-static data members of type non-POD-struct, non-POD-union (or array of such types) or reference, and has no user-defined copy assignment operator and no user-defined destructor. A POD class is a class that is either a POD-struct or a POD-union.`

Comment: Nit-pick: the version with the constructor performs an assignment to a default initialized `int` member variable. The first version doesn't. It initializes it to 5.

Comment: @Praetorian a default constructor exists anyway, right? Doesn't it have to be a user-defined constructor for it to not be an aggregate?

Comment: @Luchian You're right, I should've said *user-provided*. Found the standard ref, it's in §12.1/4 [class.ctor] (bullet that defines trivial constructor)

Comment: A thing declared in C++ with the keyword `struct`, _is a class_. Period.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings it could be a class template or an object whose type is a class.